# Pool bonding, retaining wall in the way

Tags: pool, grounding-and-bonding, retaining-wall

I currently have an 24ft intex Pool. I know it doesn't have to be bonded but while the yard is torn up I am thinking it may be a good idea to run the  bond wire now for when I upgrade the pool to a permanent one.

The problem is, I have a retaining wall on one side with a 24 inch tamped rock  base,  and about 6 to 8 inches of gravel behind the wall.

So this wall falls within 18 to 24 inches from the pool wall for where to put the halo copper wire.

Where should I put this wire?

The retaining wall blocks are  11inches deep. When i last measured, right behind the wall was 25 inches to the pool wall. And the 18 to 24inches rests over this wall area.

Comment: When you upgrade to a permanent pool each section of the galvanized wall has to be attached to the bonding wire. Plus the excavator will probalby pull your exsting wire out while digging. I would just wait until you put in the permanent pool.

Comment: @ArchonOSX, for as far as I can fathom, your suggestion is the only one that comes to mind, you should post it as the answer (most likely the best one)

Answer (score 1):

When you upgrade to a permanent pool each section of the galvanized wall has to be attached to the bonding wire. This means the bond wire has to be run after the permanent wall sections are installed since it will run through the bracing for the wall. Plus, the excavator will probalby pull your exsting wire out while digging for the permanent pool.

Given the existing pool doesn't have to be bonded, I would just wait until you put in the permanent pool.

Good luck!